# Android Studio: Application could not be installed

Tags: java, android

I've been learning android studio, today I changed just changed device for preview to Pixel did mostly layout stuff and when I run the app I get this error:

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.

List of apks:
[0] 'app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'closed'
```

I've tried to **Clean Project** and **Build it again**, I've also done **Invalidate Caches**. I don't know where is the problem. I also need to mention I also upgraded SDK from 14 to 16. Does that maybe cause the problem?

**UPDATE**

Clean Project and Build it again worked

Comment: What is interesting I've launched the app not through the virtual device but via Nexus 5X and it launched the app. Now I am more confused.

Comment: `Does that maybe cause the problem?` well, you can test that yourself, right ? revert it back and see what happens